# Android can't update UI but have log

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I want to update the TextView in the while loop.
But there is a problem. While loading, the UI can't change,but have log.Only after load,the UI can change.
Can someone tell me how to solve it.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            dfu_lib.enterdfumode("/dev/ttyS1");
            dfu_lib.open("/dev/ttyS1", "/storage/self/primary/Download/H28180-V1R5-10000.dfu", 1);
            dfu_lib.program();
            do{
                percent = dfu_lib.getpercent();
                Log.i("NF_LOG_Android_Percent", String.valueOf(percent));
                //----
                tv_percent_val.setText(String.valueOf(percent));
                //----
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }while(percent<100);
            Log.i("NF_LOG", "ttyS1 update done");
            dfu_lib.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (progressBarValue < 100) {
                progressBarValue++;

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                  // put your code***

                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```